# Looking to replace option value="" with the text between <option value="">this text</option>

Tags: regex, grep

I have this html, and I want to replace the numeric value within `value="##"` with the value between `<option>value</option>`

For example: `<option value="16">Accounting</option>`, I want to know the regex it'd take to automatically change it to `<option value="Accounting">Accounting</option>`

I plan on doing it to this entire list.

```
<option value="16">Accounting A.A.S.</option>
<option value="15">Accounting A.S.</option>
<option value="33">Art Studies</option>
<option value="18">Business Administration A.A.S.</option>
<option value="17">Business Administration A.S.</option>
<option value="20">Computer Network Technician</option>
<option value="21">Computer Support Specialist</option>
<option value="40">Criminal Justice A.A.S.</option>
<option value="39">Criminal Justice A.S.</option>
<option value="37">Criminal Justice: Corrections Certificate</option>
<option value="41">Criminal Justice: Cybersecurity</option>
<option value="42">Criminal Justice: Economic Crime</option>
<option value="43">Criminal Justice: Forensic Investigation</option>
<option value="34">Early Childhood</option>
<option value="22">Fashion Buying & Merchandising</option>
<option value="35">Fine Arts</option>
<option value="23">Health Services Management A.S.</option>
<option value="24">Health Services Management Technology A.A.S.</option>
<option value="92">Human Resource Management A.A.S.</option>
<option value="44">Human Services</option>
<option value="25">International Business</option>
<option value="36">Liberal Arts & Sciences: Childhood Education</option>
<option value="49">Liberal Arts & Sciences: Communication Arts</option>
<option value="50">Liberal Arts & Sciences: General Studies</option>
<option value="52">Liberal Arts & Sciences: Social Science</option>
<option value="51">Liberal Arts and Sciences: Humanities</option>
<option value="26">Marketing A.A.S.</option>
<option value="27">Medical Coder/Transcriptionist Certificate</option>
<option value="45">Music Industry</option>
<option value="28">Paralegal</option>
<option value="46">Photographic Technology</option>
<option value="47">Radio/Television Broadcasting</option>
<option value="91">Science A.S.</option>
<option value="29">Small Business Management</option>
<option value="30">Small Business Management: Certificate</option>
<option value="48">Teaching Assistant: Certificate</option>
<option value="31">Travel & Tourism: Hospitality & Events Management</option>
<option value="32">Website and E-Business Development</option>
```

EDIT: I want to use GREP, within textwrangler

Comment: Regex only deals with matching, so you'll need to specify the language before anyone can help you with replacement.

Comment: GREP, using textwrangler. I apologize for mixing those up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove the value attributes. `<option>` by default takes a value of it's content.

```
<option value="Accounting">Accounting</option>
```

is equivalent to:

```
<option>Accounting</option>
```

Edit: using [sed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed) you can do

```
sed -r s/' value="[0-9]+"'//g
```

Comment: Quotes generally don't need to be escaped in a regex. This is a matter of the host language's string representation. For clarity you should leave it off if you are not referring to a specific implementation.

Comment: Ok ;-) Although I like expression "better safe, then sorry" ;-)

Comment: I think putting escape characters everywhere "just in case" is a bad thing, as it raises uncertainty which part of the processing chain (in your case shell->sed->regex) gets to see what. I'd rather have the pure regex, doing my own escaping than removing escaping someone else anticipated for me.

Answer (score 2):

I assume this means you want:

```
<option value="14">Foobar</option>
```

To become:

```
<option value="Foobar">Foobar</option>
```

If so, here's the Javascript.  I assume the `select` variable contains the surrounding `<select>` tag DOM element, e.g. by `form.nameOfselect`.

```
for ( var option : select.options ) {
   option.value = option.text;
}
```

Comment: I am using textwrangler on Mac OS X and it can regex for its search/replace function.

Sorry I did not mention that.

Answer (score 1):

Under Linux:

```
sed 's|<option value="[^"]*">\([^<>]*\)</option>|<option value="\1">\1</option>|g'
```

Answer (score 1):

If your HTML is well-formed, this will do the trick:

Regex:

```
(?<=<option) value="\d+"
```

Replace with the empty string.

In HTML, option values fall back automatically to the displayed text, if no value attribute is present.

Answer (score 1):

You've added that you want to perform the operation in a text editor. I wrote something assuming you'd want to use php, and I'll let it stand here because I think it's important.

Anyway, using **TextWrangler (or any other text editor)**, replace

```
<option value="[^"]*">([^<]*)</option>
```

with

```
<option value="\1">\1</option>
```

---

As you're mostly active in the php tag, I assume you're asking for a solution in php. However, let me begin this answer with an advice: **If you are looking for a way, state your goal, not a technology you think is suitable.** regexps work, but this is far easier in [simplexml](http://php.net/simplexml):

```
$xml = str_replace("&", "&amp;", $xml); // Fix errors in your XML
$doc = simplexml_load_string($xml);
foreach ($doc->xpath("//option") as $o) {
    $o["value"] = "" . $o;
}
$xml = $doc->asXML();
```

If you insist on using a regexps, you can do so:

```
$xml = preg_replace(
    '#<option value="[^"]*">([^<]*)</option>#',
    '<option value="$1">$1</option>', $xml);
```

Comment: Thank you.  I used your first suggestion to replace the <select><option>... with <ul><li>...
  
Instead of <option value="\1">\1</option> for the replace (I used Notepad++) use:

    <li>\1</li>

Answer (score 0):

It can be made a bit more general, but it works when there are no other attributes in the option tag:

```
/(.*")([^"]+)(">)([^<]+)(.*)/
```

Then replace the captured string with this:

```
$1$4$3$4$5
```

If you're using backslash as the subgroup reference character, replace the dollar signs with backslash.

Tip: There is a great regexp tester online at http://gskinner.com/RegExr/, check it out!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but I believe this will work, using jQuery.

```
 $('option').each(function(elm) { $(this).val($(this).text()); });
```